# How to intersect arrays in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm new to ruby and i want to instersect two arrays

```
validAccountTypes = [
    'Asset' => 'Asset',
    'Liability' => 'Liability',
    'Equity' => 'Equity',
    'Income' => 'Income',
    'CostOfSales' => 'Cost of Sales',
    'Expense' => 'Expenses',
    'OtherIncome' => 'Other Income',
    'OtherExpense' => 'Other Expenses',
]

types = [
    'Asset',
    'Other Income',
    'Other Expenses',
]
```

I want a result of valid Accounts with keys base on array types. The output would be

```
[{"Asset"=>"Asset", "OtherIncome"=>"Other Income", "OtherExpense" => "Other Expenses"}]
```

Is it possible without a loop?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a rewrite of your variables with a few changes:

- Underscore variable names
- `valid_account_types` is now a hash instead of an array containing a hash.
- Some typos corrected so that the members of `types` match keys of `valid_account_types`.

  ```
  valid_account_types = {
    'Asset' => 'Asset',
    'Liability' => 'Liability',
    'Equity' => 'Equity',
    'Income' => 'Income',
    'CostOfSales' => 'Cost of Sales',
    'Expense' => 'Expenses',
    'OtherIncome' => 'Other Income',
    'OtherExpenses' => 'Other Expenses',
  }

  types = [
    'Asset',
    'OtherIncome',
    'OtherExpenses',
  ]
  ```

Given that setup, if you are using Rails, you can get the result you want using `Hash#slice`, like this:

```
> valid_account_types.slice(*types)
=> {"Asset"=>"Asset", "OtherIncome"=>"Other Income", "OtherExpenses"=>"Other Expenses"}
```

Note that `Hash#slice` does not exist in Ruby itself. If you want to do this in plain-old Ruby, you could check out [the implementation in i18n](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/6f291c427bd2df08037fbc500c529fa71b167f97/lib/i18n/core_ext/hash.rb):

```
class Hash
  def slice(*keep_keys)
    h = self.class.new
    keep_keys.each { |key| h[key] = fetch(key) if has_key?(key) }
    h
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first array isn't an array, it's actually a hash (notice the surrounding braces, rather than brackets):

```
validAccountTypes = {
    'Asset' => 'Asset',
    'Liability' => 'Liability',
    'Equity' => 'Equity',
    'Income' => 'Income',
    'CostOfSales' => 'Cost of Sales',
    'Expense' => 'Expenses',
    'OtherIncome' => 'Other Income',
    'OtherExpense' => 'Other Expenses',
}
```

You can get the keys on the hash and [intersect it](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-26) with your array:

```
common_keys = validAccountTypes.keys & types
```

Then you can select only those keys:

```
# Hash#slice works in Rails: 
validAccountTypes.slice(*common_keys)

# Otherwise use Hash#select:
validAccountTypes.select { |key, value| common_keys.include?(key) }
```

Note that in your example, your hash keys include `'OtherIncome'` and `'OtherExpense'`, but your `types` array includes `'Other Income'` and `'Other Expenses'`. Your array values should match the keys from the hash.

Comment: "Your first array isn't an array, it's actually a hash" – It's an array with a single element which is a hash.

Comment: Oh wow, you're right! Didn't realize the syntax worked that way.